# How to select sum of values in a given range from huge tables quickly (Derby)

Tags: sql, select, derby

I got A and B table like:

### Table A

```
a   b   mount
a0  b0  0.0001
a0  b1  0.0002
```

### Table B

```
c   d   weight
c0  d0  0.99998
c0  d1  0.99996
```

Each table has 10,000 - 100000 records.

I want to get all combination that `mount+weight >= 0.9998` and `mount+weight <= 0.9999`, for example:

```
a   b   c   d    sum
a0  b0  c0  d0   0.9999
a0  b1  c0  d1   0.9998
```

But if takes a lot of time when i try these ways:

#### Method 1

```
SELECT a b c d mount+weight
FROM A,B 
WHERE mount+weight >= 0.9998 and mount+weight <= 0.9999
```

A table have index of mount, B table have index of weight

#### Method 2

Create `A+B` table, but it takes more time than method 1.

Is there any ways to improve?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, mount+weight as mw
FROM A,B 
WHERE mount+weight between 0.9998 and 0.9999
```

This may produce a slightly different execution plan

Edit: I just realised this is for Derby. Not even sure if BETWEEN is available in Derby

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Yes, I've tried "between", but it didn't improve very much.
I also tried this way:
SELECT a, b, c, d, mount+weight as mw
FROM A,B 
WHERE mount<= 0.9999
AND weight<=0.9999
AND mount+weight between 0.9998 and 0.9999

In this way, it improve a lot ,but still also take a lot of time to finish.